# How can I tell if a .Net format string is valid?

Tags: c#, .net

.Net includes a [wide range of built in formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types) to control the output when converting an object to a string e.g. `ToString("N2")`. How can I test if a given format string is actually valid?

If I pass a garbage formatter `ToString(...)` then the output seems to be the literal of that formatter. For example (in my `en` locale):

```
10.ToString("F");    // Outputs '10.00'
10.ToString("typo"); // Outputs 'typo'
```

I am trying to catch the case where a format has been overridden in one of our translations (perhaps by a non-developer), and the format has been accidentally typo'd.

It seems strange that an invalid formatter is allowed through without exception, and even more strange that when this case does occur, the invalid formatter is used as the output instead of falling back to the source object.

Comment: How will you differentiate between bad format string from cases where ToString is overridden?

Comment: Write unit tests  expected output

Comment: Thanks @41686d6564 - I hadn't seen that when I searched. The brute force way of validating against the list would cover what we need. Although it would be rather verbose to implement, given that we are not limited to just numeric types, but all built-ins.

Comment: It may not be what is desired, but `"typo"` *is* a valid format string.  See [the docs about character literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#character-literals), the part about "All other characters..."

Comment: @AndySavage note that if you simply don't put formatting strings into localized resources that whole problem disappears... Keep formatting in the code and use just non-formtting `"The value is {0}"` placeholders in localized string.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov Not only does that remove the functionality of being able to override formats, that also puts the responsibility for formatting on the development team and not the team responsible for localisation (or even just content).

Comment: @AndySavage the question suggest that "one of our translations (perhaps by a non-developer)" - which may imply that localizers you have may not have much experience with format strings (which I'm pretty sure is common in the industry). Indeed if your case requires format strings to be localized *per language* (which is dangerous unless you do full set of localized strings for all Language-Country pairs) than indeed putting formatting into resource strings is ok. I find explaining just proper translations to be hard, try to explain "FR-CA and FR-FR must have different negative currency format".

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if this is really the best approach, however using [types that implement IFormattable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable?view=net-5.0):

<sub>***Note** : that this is likely to give you false positives and unexpected behaviour in certain formats. The only other option is to create a white list (which would in any implementation be equally flawed)*</sub>

```
public static bool TryFormat<T>(this T target, string format, out string result)
   where T : IFormattable
{
   result = null;
   try
   {
      return (result = target.ToString(format,null)) != format;
   }
   catch 
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
if(!10.TryFormat("Typo", out var test))
   Console.WriteLine("yeah nah");
```

Comment: `DateTime` implements `IFormattable`, but will fail this test because the `y` in `Typo` will be interpreted as [the "y custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#year-y-format-specifier).  I assume similar issues will arise with other types and their respective tokens.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint indeed you are correct. I should put a big disclaimer

Comment: @00110001 oh well if you were going to be corrected by anyone at least its the *jon skeet nodatime* Microsoftie equivalent! Good day to you two.